# What's the opposite of "authenticator"?

Tags: antonyms, er-ee

What's the opposite of "authenticator"?

An [authenticator](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/authenticator) is:

> "a person or thing that authenticates."

What do you call the person who is being authenticated?
Assuming the use case where a person authenticates another person.

Comment: I'd say the **opposite** of _authenticator_ is _repudiator_ or _invalidator_. I agree with Jeremy that _authenticatee_ is the logical choice for the word you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is an official word for that, but I'd have coined "authenticatee" (compare "employee": a person who is employed). Google search reveals that Oracle uses "authenticatee" in its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-0204/pppsvrconfig.intro-14/index.html). You could probably get by with this in technical documentation, as I suspect the intent would be understood. Otherwise I'd suggest "authenticated person" or "candidate for authentication" (depending on whether the authentication is complete or pending).

Comment: Thanks. I thought of authenticatee before but couldn't find it in any official dictionary.